# Javascript/Jquery "create" elements with .html() and .append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, database, html

This is a part of code from my little "Online-Shop", you can see that I append a table to my main div.

```
$('div.main').html('<table class="clothes">' +
                '<tr>' +
                '<td><div class="product"><img class="product_img" src="men_jacket1.jpg"><div class="price"><span class="price_text">95 €</span> <div id="m1" class="price_img-wrapper"><img src="cart_mini.png"></div></div></div></td>' +
                '<td><div class="product"><img class="product_img" src="men_jacket2.jpg"><div class="price"><span class="price_text">70 €</span> <div id="m2" class="price_img-wrapper"><img src="cart_mini.png"></div></div></div></td>' +
                '<td><div class="product"><img class="product_img" src="men_jacket3.jpg"><div class="price"><span class="price_text">55 €</span> <div id="m3" class="price_img-wrapper"><img src="cart_mini.png"></div></div></div></td>' +
                '</tr>' +
                '<tr>' +
                '<td><div class="product"><img class="product_img" src="men_tshirt1.jpg"><div class="price"><span class="price_text">10 €</span> <div id="m4" class="price_img-wrapper"><img src="cart_mini.png"></div></div></div></td>' +
                '<td><div class="product"><img class="product_img" src="men_tshirt2.jpg"><div class="price"><span class="price_text">25 €</span> <div id="m5" class="price_img-wrapper"><img src="cart_mini.png"></div></div></div></td>' +
                '<td><div class="product"><img class="product_img" src="men_tshirt3.jpg"><div class="price"><span class="price_text">30 €</span> <div id="m6" class="price_img-wrapper"><img src="cart_mini.png"></div></div></div></td>' +
                '</tr>' +
                '<tr>' +
                '<td><div class="product"><img class="product_img" src="men_trouser1.jpg"><div class="price"><span class="price_text">20 €</span> <div id="m7" class="price_img-wrapper"><img src="cart_mini.png"></div></div></div></td>' +
                '<td><div class="product"><img class="product_img" src="men_trouser2.jpg"><div class="price"><span class="price_text">70 €</span> <div id="m8" class="price_img-wrapper"><img src="cart_mini.png"></div></div></div></td>' +
                '<td><div class="product"><img class="product_img" src="men_trouser3.jpg"><div class="price"><span class="price_text">45 €</span> <div id="m9" class="price_img-wrapper"><img src="cart_mini.png"></div></div></div></td>' +
                '</tr>' +
                '</table>');
```

My question is: Is this the right way to append or create html elements and if not, why? 
For example, I got the price, img, etc. from a database, work this code if I insert it with my idea?

Comment: It's not incorrect, but it's unwieldy and very repetitive..

Comment: Why are you even doing that, isn't the content static anyway?

Comment: When I need to get data from javascript to html, I try to write out as much of the HTML as possible first.  When looking at the HTML file, you can see what is supposed to be there, and when looking at the javascript, it's not so clunky and hard to read and repetitive.

Comment: @Jack William In my example for school, the content was static, but if I got the dates from a database, I need a other idea..

Comment: @Jacob Raccuia how would you do this by my example?

Comment: if you look at what @arieljuod did in #2. essentially, you are selecting html with jquery and putting in content.

Comment: @JacobRaccuia ok you mean this with "write out as much of the html as possible" thanks, now I understand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to better methods:

1 - Use .load() and return the html on the request

```
$('div.main').load(some_url);
```

now, use an url form your website that renders the table you need (only the table) and you are done, you define html serverside and jquery only load it, I would do this

2 - Use jQuery to create elements, this give you more control

```
var table = $('<table>').addClass('clothes');
var tr = $('<tr>');
var td = $('<td>');
var div = $('<div>')addClass('product');
var img = $('<img>').addClass('product_img').attr('src',"men_trouser1.jpg");
div.append(img);
td.append(div);
tr.append(td);
table.append(tr);
$('div.main').append(table);
```

it's ugly because using javascript to create html is always ugly, at least this way have more control (you could create the td's inside a loop and append them one by one). I would the the first method, create the table serverside

Comment: Is there other way to create html, which is not so ugly?

" I would the the first method, create the table serverside" What do you mean with this sentence?

But thank you, I like your code, but I dont understand 1. what do you mean here?
Grateful, Nico

Comment: Maybe you can find a jquery plugin to create tables easier, but I wouldn't recommend that either. What I meant was that I would use the first method, not the seconds one, the first is the best (at least for me) way to do what you want unless you have a real need to do it all in javascript. I'll edit method 1 with an explanation

Answer (score 1):

My humble advice would be to use some form of javascript templating engine. I often use the variation of [John Resig microtemplating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) that is included in [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), a wonderful little library with more than 80 utility functions which is by itself a little treasure.

It goes something like this:

In your html you define the template inside an appropriate tag, the example is for underscore/Resig microtemplating. 
In your case I would use a loop to iterate through the products

```
<script type="text/template" id="clothesTableTemplate">
  <table class="clothes">
    <% clothes.forEach(function(cloth){ %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="product">
          <img class="product_img" src="<%- cloth.imgSrc %>">
          <div class="price">
            <span class="price_text"><%- cloth.priceText %></span> 
            <div id="m1" class="price_img-wrapper">
              <img src="cart_mini.png">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <% }); %>
  </table>
</script>
```

Then you can call the template from your js like this:

```
// say you got this data from the db

var clothes = [
  {
    imgSrc: 'men_jacket1.jpg',
    priceText: '95 €'
  },
  {
    imgSrc: 'men_jacket2.jpg',
    priceText: '70 €'
  }
];

var clothesTemplate = _.template(
  $("script#clothesTableTemplate").html()
);

$('div.main').html(clothesTemplate(clothes));

// With little modifications we could also define a template containing
// only the row and append single rows to the table
```

Other widely used templating systems are [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) and [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)

Another, somewhat different approach is that of [Knockout js](http://knockoutjs.com/), it's very clean and something I'd wholeheartedly suggest to look into.

Answer (score 0):

to append, you use something like this

```
$('div.main').append('blablab');
```

the $('div.main).html is in fact equal to

```
document.getElementById('div.main').innerHTML = 'blablab';
```

It is correct JQuery syntax but I don't recommend just addin static HTML using Javascript, which doesn't get any advantages.

Comment: P.S.: A vanilla javascript append would look like: `document.getElementById('div.main').innerHTML += 'blablab';`